# Ion-Tabs can't get the value of ng-model in view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the code below that has a `tab` at the bottom part of the screen (act as a button on a footer) with a function which will get the value of `ng-model` from input. But it returns `undefined`, while I also tested it out on `button` with same code, it output the expected result.

I am wondering why?

**View**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-left">
  <ion-tab title="Submit Ticket" ng-click="sayHello(send)">

       <label class="item item-input">
         <input type="text" ng-model="send.subject">
       </label>  

    <button ng-click="sayHello(send)">
                Submit Message
    </button>

  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.sayHello = function(send) {
    alert(send);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you click ion-tab you are already calling the sayHello function which will send an undefined value.

you should remove the other ng-click

```
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-left">
    <ion-tab title="Submit Ticket">
        <label class="item item-input">
           <input type="text" ng-model="send.subject">
         </label>
        <button ng-click="sayHello(send)">Submit Message</button>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```